# Find the simplified form of $\frac {1}{\cos x + \sin x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find the simplified form of $\dfrac {1}{\cos x + \sin x}$.

a). $\dfrac {\sin (\dfrac {\pi}{4} +x)}{\sqrt {2}}$

b). $\dfrac {\csc (\dfrac {\pi}{4} + x)}{\sqrt {2}}$

c). $\dfrac {\sin (\dfrac {\pi}{4} + x)}{2}$

d). $\dfrac {\csc (\dfrac {\pi}{4} + x)}{2}$

My Attempt:
$$=\dfrac {1}{\cos x + \sin x}$$
$$=\dfrac {1}{\cos x + \sin x} \times \dfrac {\cos x - \sin x}{\cos x - \sin x}$$
$$=\dfrac {\cos x - \sin x}{\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x}$$
$$=\dfrac {\cos x - \sin x}{\cos 2x}$$

Comment: Do you know about the dot product? If so consider $\langle 1,1 \rangle \cdot \langle \cos x,\sin x \rangle$. If not guess that you can write $\cos x+\sin x=A \cos (x+b)$ and solve for $A,b$ that will work.

Comment: If you're lazy like me you can plug in some values of $x$ and see which of the options fit.

Comment: Plug in $x=0$: The value should be $1$, so only $(b)$ satisfies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{\cos(x) + \sin(x)} = \frac{\sqrt2/2}{\sqrt2/2*\cos(x) + \sqrt2/2*\sin(x)} = \frac{\sqrt2/2}{\sin(\pi/4+x)} = \frac{\csc(\pi/4 + x)}{\sqrt2}$$

Comment: How do you get past the second equals sign?

Comment: @MattGutting $\sin(a+b) = \sin(a)*\cos(b) + \sin(b)*\cos(a)$. In this case, $\sin(\pi/4) = \cos(\pi/4) = \sqrt2/2$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is the graph of the function $\sin x+\cos x$.
Notice that itself looks like a wave.

So, we should be able to deduce that(since only the amplitude and phase seem to have changed),
$$\sin x+\cos x=A\sin( x+\phi)$$
Expanding using the identity for $\sin(A+B)$,
$$\sin x+\cos x=A\sin( x)\cos\phi+A\cos(x)\sin\phi$$

Comparing the coefficients of $\sin $ and $\cos,
$$1=A\cos\phi$$
$$1=A\sin\phi$$

Assuming non-zero $\cos$,dividing the second equation by the first gives:
$$1=\tan\phi\implies \phi=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

We only need one solution so we won"t worry about other solutions.
Now squaring the equations and adding,
$$2=A^2\implies A=\sqrt{2}$$